# Вызов метода из другого класса Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Всем доброго вечера. Есть у меня 2 класса на 1 ViewController. 
В первом классе мне нужно вызвать метод, реализованный во втором классе. Почитав несколько статей, в том числе и на этом сайте, я вроде бы разобрался как это сделать, но где-то ошибаюсь.

Ситуация такова.

Второй класс (с методом), унаследован от UITableViewCell

```
#import "B757_table.h"
@implementation CheckLabelCell

-(void)checkOff:(int)sender {
//некоторый код
}

@end
```

А вот первый класс, в котором мне его нужно вызвать

Кусочек хедер файла:

```
   #import "CheckLabelCell.h"

    @interface B757_table : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource> {
    // он используется для таблицы в том числе
```

Файл реализации

```
#import "B757_table.h"
#import "CheckLabelCell.h"

@interface B757_table ()

@end

@implementation B757_table

-(IBAction)checkAll:(id)sender{
    CheckLabelCell *obj = [[CheckLabelCell alloc]init];
    [obj CheckOff:0]; 
// на этом месте он мне выдает ошибку "No visible @interface for 'CheckLabelCell' declares the selector 'CheckOff:' "
}

@end
```

Как видно, экземпляр класса я создал, но он все равно ругается. Не знаю уже как решить сей проблему.

Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вероятно, Вы не определили метод в интерфейсе класса в заголовочном файле, поэтому метод и не видно при импорте хедера в другие файлы?

```
@interface CheckLabelCell : UITableViewCell

-(void)checkOff:(int)sender;

@end
```

Comment: Да, вы правы, дело было в этом